# Node/Express: Use a function request from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, backend

Firstly, I'm a frontend developer so I'm sorry if I use wrong terms in my explanations.

In my company, we are actually building 1 web app and 2 API apps. So the users use the web app which talks to the first API which talks to the second API.

Here, we are in the first API, in the server.js file:

```
server.js
---------

var app = express();

const cats = require("./api/cats");

app.get("/animals/cats", cats.listTheCats); // listTheCats() returns an array of cats
```

In cats.js, we can see with listTheCats() we are sending another request to the second API:

```
cats.js
-------

const listTheCats = (req, res) => {
    axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "http://second-api-url.com/animals/cats",
        params: req.query,
    })
        .then((ans) => {
            res.status(ans.data.status).json(ans.data.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            res.sendStatus(503);
        });
};

module.exports = listTheCats;
```

The code above works fine on the web app. But now, in the first api, in another file called "cuteAnimals.js" I need to call listTheCats(). So I tried to do this but it doesn't work:

```
cuteAnimals.js
--------------

const { listTheCats } = require("./cats");

const fetchCats = async () => {
    const params = {
        type: "cute",
    };

    const cuteCats = await axios.get(`animals/cats`, {
        params,
    });

    // or const cuteCats = await listTheCats(params);

    console.log("cuteCats", cuteCats);
 };

fetchCats();
```

This is the error: "Request failed with status code 400"

In cuteAnimals.js, is it right to use axios from a file to another file of the same server project?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this line was already written in my my code, I forgot to add it to my post here...

Comment: How are the params used in your last snippet?

Comment: In the code block "cats.js" just above, the "params" object is supposed to be in the req.query propriety which is assigned to the "params" propriety of the get request. That's why I suspect my way to use axios in the "cuteAnimals.js" file to be wrong. I'm not even sure that the url "animals/cats" points the server port. In "cuteAnimals.js", I also tried to directly use the imported listTheCats() function instead of axios.get(...) but I got "undefined" when I log the result. It behaves with no delay as it was synchronous but it shouldn't and using async/await words doesn't fix it..

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the function in order to use it in another file, you can do it simply by writing this line at the end of cats.js

```
module.exports = listTheCats
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this line was already written in my my code, I forgot to add it to my post here...